# Positive semidefinite linear operator $T$ satisfies $T^k=I$. Is $T$ the identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

I got the following question in an exam I got yesterday that I didn't managed to answer:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional unitary vector space and let $T:V \to V$ be a positive semidefinite linear transformation and we know that there exist an integer $k \geq 1$ such that $T^k=I$, Must it be the case that $T=I$?

Thanks.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $T$ must be real, positive and satisfy $\lambda^{k}-1=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that
$$
0=T^k-I=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (T-\omega^j I),
$$
where $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/k)$. But as $T$ is positive semidefinite, all its eigenvalues are real and non-negative, and
this implies that $T-\omega I$ is non-singular, where $\omega\ne 1$ is a $k$th root of $1.$
In particular
$$
S=\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} (T-\omega^j I)
$$
is non-singular, and hence
$$
0=S^{-1}(T^k-I)=S^{-1}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (T-\omega^j I)=T-I.
$$
Thus $T=I$.